# How to require admin confirmation of registered users with AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using the Cognito Hosted UI option to register and sign-in users for my website. Currently, users who register are immediately able to sign-in using their username/password. This is an issue because this allows anyone to register and then to access restricted parts of the site. What I would like to do is require that the ADMIN manually confirm every registered user before they can login.

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to manually confirm every user that has registered using your Cognito User Pool, you could perform the following steps:

**Step 1**: Ensure that E-Mail/SMS verification requirement is unchecked in the  "MFA and Verifications" sidebar in your Amazon Cognito User Pool console.

**Step 2**: To improve user experience, utilize a custom UI for your web/mobile application. After your users sign-up, redirect them to a different web-page which states that they would require admin verification. If you are using the Cognito default UI, the message "User Pool not configured properly for confirmation code delivery" which doesn't necessarily deliver a seamless user experience.

**Step 3**: Now, your signed up users should have the "UNCONFIRMED" state in the Amazon Cognito User Pool.

**Step 4**: To manually confirm the user, you can use the AdminConfirmSignUp API call[1], from your application code or from the CLI. This requires the user-pool-id and the username, and would also need Administrator credentials for it to run successfully.

I tested this out on my end, and I was able to manually confirm all the users that had registered to my Amazon Cognito User Pool. 
The API call I tried on my end is as follows(tested via the CLI):

```
aws cognito-idp admin-confirm-sign-up --user-pool-id us-east-1_XXXX --username XXXX
```

After the AdminConfirmSignUp API call, your "UNCONFIRMED" users should have the "CONFIRMED" status.

## References

[1]. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminConfirmSignUp.html

Comment: Why would you uncheck email verification? Shouldn't the users verify their email before being confirmed?